# How to force iOS lib compression to LZ4 compress in one block?

Tags: ios, swift, compression, lz4

I'd like to compress a buffer whose size is greater than 64Kb in only one block.

I currently use lib compression to LZ4 compress/decompress, which works fine with buffer lower than 64Kb. Provided I stripped Apple extras header from the block as Apple adds extra bytes described in [the doc right there](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compression/data_compression), stating:
The frame is documented here so that you can easily wrap another LZ4 encoder/decoder to produce/consume the same data stream if necessary. An LZ4 encoded buffer is a sequence of blocks, each of which begins with a header. There are three possible headers:

> ```
>      1) A compressed block header consists of:
>         a) the octets 0x62, 0x76, 0x34, and 0x31,
>         b) followed by the size in bytes of the decoded (plaintext) data represented by the block
>         c) and the size (in bytes) of the encoded data stored in the block.
> ```

Unfortunately, as I didn't found a way to force compress in only one block (is it possible? Regular LZ4 compressor provides a maxBlockSize to address this), it generates multiple blocks (for a maxBlockSize of 64Kb). If I strip all headers, it is virtually impossible to decompress, not knowing where the border is in between blocks.

Wrapping up, my question is:
— is it possible to force the compressor to generate only one block?

My extension to strip extras off in a one-block situation :

```
import Compression

extension Data {

   public func lz4Compress(removeAppleExtras:Bool, compressedBufferSize: Int = 500_000) -> Data? {
        func print(_ text: String) {
            Swift.print("Data.lz4Compress(): \(text)")
        }

        // Data to compress is self
        let dataToCompress = self

        let compressedBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: compressedBufferSize)

        guard let compressedSize = withUnsafeBytes ({ (dataToCompressBuffer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Int? in

            return compression_encode_buffer(
                compressedBuffer,     compressedBufferSize,
                dataToCompressBuffer, dataToCompress.count,
                nil,
                COMPRESSION_LZ4
            )

        }) else {
            print("*** Error: Unable to compress, returned size is 0 ")
            return nil
        }

        // Turn to Data not duplicating buffer
        let compressed = Data(bytesNoCopy: compressedBuffer, count: compressedSize, deallocator: .free)

        guard removeAppleExtras else {
            return compressed
        }

        // We must remove Apple extra header/footer

        let cz = compressedSize

        let axHeader            =  UInt32(bigEndian:    compressed.subdata(in:    0 ..<  4).withUnsafeBytes{$0.pointee})
        let axUncompressedSize  =  UInt32(littleEndian: compressed.subdata(in:    4 ..<  8).withUnsafeBytes{$0.pointee})
        let axCompressedSize    =  UInt32(littleEndian: compressed.subdata(in:    8 ..< 12).withUnsafeBytes{$0.pointee})

        print("LZ4 Apple extras for compressed size of \(compressedSize.hex()) (\(compressedSize)), uncompressed: \(dataToCompress.count.hex()) (\(dataToCompress.count))")
        print("Apple Header:     \(axHeader.hex()) (\(compressed.subdata(in: 0..<4).ascii()))")
        print("UncompressedSize: \(axUncompressedSize.hex()) (\(axUncompressedSize))")
        print("CompressedSize:   \(axCompressedSize.hex()) (\(axCompressedSize))")

        let bareBonesCompressed =                       compressed.subdata(in:   12 ..< (cz-4))

        let axFooter            =  UInt32(bigEndian:    compressed.subdata(in: cz-4 ..< cz).withUnsafeBytes{$0.pointee})

        print("Apple footer:     \(axFooter.hex()) (\(compressed.subdata(in: cz-4 ..< cz).ascii()))")

        return bareBonesCompressed
    }      // Data.lz4Compress()
}
```